# how to get the equation of a line that passes through (0, 0, 1) and parallel to the xy plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I understand that since its parallel to the xy plane then the z value would be zero but not sure about how to get the equation itself

Comment: You have a point. All that is left to find is the direction vector for the line. Since the line should be parallel to the xy-plane, any vector lying in the xy-plane will work fine as your direction vector. For example $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{i}$. The equation of a line in space can be represented by the following vector-valued function: $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x_0,y_0,x_0)+t\mathbf{v}$. So, the equation of one possible line that satisfies the conditions laid out in the problem statement would be: $$\mathbf{r}(t)=(0,0,1)+t\mathbf{i}=t\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{k}.$$

Comment: Please avoid ['I have no clue'](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) questions. Have you tried writing down the equation of a line in vector form, and then applying that to the question.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477885/265466.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many such lines. If we choose any direction parallel to the $xy$-plane, using a vector in this plane (such as $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$), we simply obtain the parametric equation $(0,0,1) + \lambda (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The directions parallel to $xy$-plane are all such that $z=0$ in the direction-determining vector of the line.

So you'd have $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\0\end{pmatrix}$  for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$